# OpenSolver and Excel's Solver gives different optimal solutions

Tags: microsoft-excel, solver

I noticed that OpenSolver and Solver tend to give different solutions. For example, in the example [file](https://www.linearprogramming.info/wp-content/uploads/2017/02/OpenSolver-Excel.xlsx) provided by this [website](https://www.linearprogramming.info/how-to-solve-a-linear-programming-model-with-opensolver/), OpenSolver gives an answer of X=0 and Y=60, whereas Solver's is X=10 and Y=45. Any idea why is this so? Which one should I trust?

(edit)
The file is essentially modeling the problem below:

> Maximize: 30X+20Y
>
> Subject to:
> 5X+2Y <= 140
> 3X+2Y <= 120
> X,Y >= 0

Comment: Questions should be self containing, please include core description of the example so that people can reproduce it without downloading the file.

Answer (score 1):

Linear equation systems like your one may have multiple solutions.

Both types of solver uses kinds of approximation algorithms to find a solution, not analytic methods to solve your equations, this means:

- in case of multiple optimal output, selection of them depends on initial parameters too (starting Excel's solver with x=0, y=0 will stay there, won't change to 10, 45)
- These algorithms can be implemented differently, they may find different results

> Which one should I trust?

Always check the output, if both are within criteria and results the same final output, then both can be correct.

---

If you want to get a definite answer, you need to use a proper tool, e.g. [Wolfram Alpha](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=maximize+30*x%2B20*y,+5*x%2B2*y%3C%3D140,+3*x%2B2*y%3C%3D120,+x%3E%3D0,+y%3E%3D0):

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Both of these Excel solutions satisfy the constraints, and have the same objective value, and so both are correct.

Comment: This reads like a comment on the existing answer rather than an answer in its own right. It would be better to explain *why* both solutions are correct rather than that they just are. See the existing answer for an example of how this should be written.